# Run gpu-opencv based application anywhere

Tags: opencv

How is it possible to have one executable (based on opencv 2.4.3 with CUDA support enabled) with runtime check for CUDA presence and dispatching whether to use gpu or cpu algorithm from opencv?

gpu-opencv based application simple does not start on machine without CUDA (cudart, nvcuda dlls needed).

[clew](https://github.com/martijnberger/clew) does this trick for OpenCL.